# Can I get a contour of the opencv grabcut function?

Tags: c++, opencv

I am using opencv grabcut function for image segmentation. I have looked at the sample given in opencv of the grabcut usage, the sample is simply returning as an image where all the "background" parts are colored as black (0,0,0) . I can simply flood from every black point and get the contour. But I would like to use given function if they exist.

Comment: what about `findCountours`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Grabcut returns a mask. You can use this code to get the contours:

```
std::vector<std::vector<cv::Point> > contours;
cv::findContours(mask, contours, CV_RETR_EXTERNAL, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);
```